# Portable python app to run on remote systems

Tags: python, portability

I am in need to generate a standalone portable python application and run on remote systems where even python interpreter is not installed or version is different.

The aim will be to pack the python script as an app, transfer it to the remote systems and run it as a standalone app without any dependencies.

Do we have such a way in the Python world? Has anybody done a similar thing before?

Comment: There is something called `py2exe`, you can compile your script to executable exe file. But to be honest this solution does not work without problems.

Comment: What kinds of systems are we talking about? What is available to users, and how far will the users of those systems go to make this work? (i.e. can you distribute a VM image? What about Docker image? Can they use tools like Ansible / Puppet?)

Answer (score 2):

**Freezing** is the name of the game.

Here's an example using `PyInstaller`.

A sample script `test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import reduce


my_list = list('1234567890')

my_list = list(map(lambda x: int(x), my_list))
my_sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, my_list)

print("The sum of %s is %d" % (list(my_list), my_sum))
```

To create a binary from the script, install `PyInstaller` and run it on your code:

```
$ pyinstaller -F test.py
```

After it finishes, you should find the standalone binary in `./dist`. When you run it, it behaves just like any other program:

```sh
$ ./dist/test
The sum of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] is 45
```

For more information, take a look [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. PyInstaller is gaining a lot of popularity and supports a lot of systems (and Python 3), and also GUI packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want portability even more than what Python already provides as you mentioned that Python interpreter might not be there on remote system, most suitable way for you could be to compile it as Java application. You can follow the steps below.

1. install JDK and VisAD-Jython from jython.org(a python to jar compiler)
2. Make a batch file (or script) in the VisAD-Jython install directory to invoke the jythonc compiler. Below is an example script. let's name it abc.bat

   ```
   @echo off
   set JYTHON_PATH=.
   set CLASSPATH=.
   %JYTHON_PATH%\jre\bin\java.exe -mx256m "-Dpython.home=%JYTHON_PATH%\\" "-Dpython .path=%JYTHON_PATH%.\\" -cp "%JYTHON_PATH%\\jython.jar;%JYTHON_PATH%\\visad.jar; %JYTHON_PATH%\\;." org.python.util.jython "%JYTHON_PATH%\Tools\jythonc\jythonc.p y " --compiler javac  %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
   ```
3. Then to compile your .py script like below:

   ```
   abc --core --jar new.jar new.py
   ```

Now you can port and run it anywhere with Java.

Comment: By what metric is this "most efficient"?

Comment: Given your requirement to be able to run it on any remote system, you can find Java installed or easily install it without worrying about platform and dependencies on most of the systems. Also it won't take much of a work compiling.

Comment: As compared to Python? I don't think so... Also, I'm not the original poster, I was just surprised to hear that Java is suggested to make Python more cross-platform when, probably, the opposite is true (i.e. by bundling Python inside Java you make it far less likely that the application will be easy to distribute and to install).

Comment: Didn't notice that you're not the poster. Although python requires only an interpreter setup but the question has it mentioned specifically that the OP doesn't necessarily have one on the remote system. While java on the other hand, is already setup on far more systems. what you say is generically more acceptable but here I think he/she wants to run it on a remote system that he might not have privilege to install another programs.

Comment: Java requires an interpreter too, but Java interpreter is written in Java and is a lot less portable (try compiling JVM for a system not supported by the JDK of your choice). To contrast that Python is written in C, so, compiling Python for your platform may just work out of the box, or, perhaps, require very little patching. Most Linux systems in the wild (which is about 99% of computers out there, if you don't concentrate on just PC market) don't have Java installed, while Python is almost a requirement nowadays.

Comment: I have also edited the term "most efficient". gives a false impression. thanks

Comment: @wvxvw , just because python is based on C doesn't mean that you can EXECUTE it everywhere. you first need an interpreter installed. and JVM is far more used on the systems than python.

Comment: But that's not what I'm saying... I say that Python's interpreter is easier to port to new system because it is written in C, which has a good record of portability (whereas Java doesn't). JVM is installed on far, far fewer computers in the wild than Python. There are very few Linux distros which bundle Java in their installations, while Python is usually there because package managers are often written in Python (dnf and apt for example). Python is embedded deep in Linux system code, while Java plays no role there, so it's much more common to find Python than Java in that environment.

Comment: JVM is as easily portable as it gets. jar file made on 10 years older OS can run easily without any dependency on a latest system and java supports full backwards dependency(while python has a whole 2 vs 3 debate going on :P). now it just falls back on the OP what kind of application it is and environment it needs to be run on. I wish we could move the further discussion to chat box but I don't have enough repo.

Comment: Sorry, you really don't know what "portable" means. You are talking about backward compatibility... portable means that you can take a program (in our case JVM), and run it on a system other than it was initially written for. JVM was initially written for Solaris, but then ported for Linux, Mac, Windows, BSD, HP-UX etc. It is a huge effort to port JVM to another system (Google undertook this not so long ago when porting JVM for Android).

Comment: Backwards compatibility is a property of a program that describes the likelihood of the new version of the program breaking when consuming input that didn't break older version of the same program.

Comment: Python 3 vs 2 is both backward and forward compatibility issue, JVM has only forward compatibility and vendor compatibility issues (some classes in Sun / Oracle JVM are not available in OpenJDK, some classes added in newer JVM are not available in old versions).

Comment: Ok my final comment, if you want to discuss further you can hit me personally and not convert it into spamming as it is public post. So you said, "in our case JVM", why are you trying to port the whole JVM? I said porting the program that is supposed to be run by JVM. of course JVM on one machine can't be run on another, because they are different.

Let's say I have a python program a.py. I convert it into jar -> a.jar. now I can run this jar anywhere that has a JVM installed. why would I carry the JVM itself? that's what the OP wants and this approach is doing it easily .

Comment: please don't make this already long thread even more as it is not useful for anyone here. Whoever might be wrong/right, we can argue personally.
batra.manish4@gmail.com

Comment: Spamming? Seriously? You suggested a nonsense solution to a problem you don't really understand, and you won't take a hint... that your "solution" might be harmful, especially in a public forum, because, who knows, maybe someone clueless, but endowed with administrative power may actually read this and think that it makes sense. There are tons of examples of nonsense answers on SO with hundreds of upvotes.