# How to check if the condition is true for the next n minutes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a list of time intervals with a column of conditions as shown

Intervals:

```
Time                 Count  Bool Hit 
2013-01-02 11:03:00   50    0    NaN
2013-01-02 11:10:00   63    0    NaN
2013-01-02 11:11:00   128   1    NaN
2013-01-02 11:12:00   283   0    NaN
2013-01-02 11:13:00   110   0    NaN
2013-01-02 12:14:00   89    0    NaN
2013-01-02 12:20:00   23    0    NaN
```

I would like to output `True` in the `Hit` column if `bool==1` in the next 5 minutes leading to the following output.

```
Time                 Count  Bool Hit 
2013-01-02 11:03:00   50    0    NaN
2013-01-02 11:10:00   63    0    1
2013-01-02 11:11:00   128   1    NaN
2013-01-02 11:12:00   283   0    NaN
2013-01-02 11:13:00   110   0    NaN
2013-01-02 12:14:00   89    0    NaN
2013-01-02 12:20:00   23    0    NaN
```

I have tried several methods using pd.resample and pd.DateOffSet but I am unable to find a quick solution.

A sample code that I have written is as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv("data/csv/2013.csv") 
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(cc['DateTime'],format="%d/%m/%Y%H:%M") 
def hitrate(DateTime):
    df.loc[df['bool'] ==1, 'Hit'] = 1 
df_test=df.resample(rule='10min',on='DateTime').apply(hitrate)
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific about the rule you're trying to create?

You enter `1` into the `Hit` column even though entries from the next 5 minutes after that record have `0`s in `Bool`. Did you mean **last 5 minutes**?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The 5 minutes period includes the minute that I start counting from i.e. 11:10 to 11:15. Conversely, it is also possible to do it from the perspective of the last 5 minutes although I am not sure if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. But why does `2013-01-02 11:10:00` get a 1 in `Hit` if `2013-01-02 11:11:00`'s `Bool` is 0, shouldn't the next 0 be at least 5 minutes in the future?

Comment: That is true. I have amended the example for clarity. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi @Stanisław. One of your [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009592) was deleted in the review queue, very soon after you improved it a great deal. I have flagged it to ask a moderator to consider restoring it. If that does not happen, feel free to flag it yourself, or raise it on Meta.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, great to know that my answer was helpful. @justin, I think that the `pandas.rolling_apply` function might prove helpful to you. You should use it with a window of 2 and then compare the offset of each two date indices

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks for the tip.